# Combo box behaviour incorrect when placed on the menu bar

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a question - why is the behaviour of the comboBox different when it is located on a menu bar like below? 
The problem is that when I click the comboBox (to provide the URL address) I cannot type - it seems that focus is immediately lost. I have to click on the dropdown list icon, and only then I can type in.

If I move this ComboBox outside the menu bar, I can use it the way I want.

```
 <Menu Height="auto" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBox Name="urls_list" IsEditable="True" Width="220" Height="auto"  Loaded="urls_list_Loaded"></ComboBox>
            <MenuItem Header="Options"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="About"></MenuItem>
 </Menu>
```

To give you a little background - I want to have a menu bar on top of the window with a few menu buttons and the "address bar" that allows to both type new addresses or use the predefined ones, but it is very annoying that you can't start typing in right away.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Set property <Menu FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False">

Comment: Well, that should be an answer! Thank you:)

Comment: @HeenaPatil, can you please add your comment as an answer (preferably with a little textual description), so that this question can be marked as answered? Thanks.